Finding the non-trivial block of a finite dimensional algebra via GAP
Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $K$-algebra that has a block decomposition $A=A_1 \times A_2 \times \dots\times A_n$. (we can assume that $A$ is a quiver algebra if that helps, meaning all simple $A$-modules are 1-dimensional over the field).
Now I know that all blocks $A_i$ for $i \geq 2$ are trivial and only $A_1$ is non-trivial.

Question 1: Is there an easy way to obtain the algebra $A_1$ using GAP (and maybe the package QPA) given the algebra $A$?


Question 2: Is it even more generally possible to obtain the single blocks of a given algebra $A$?


If $K$ is a finite field, this can de done with the Meataxe, see here.
If $K$ has characteristic 0, then I think this is difficult in general and I don't know any fully generic solution. But depending on the exact structure of $A$ there is a chance. Indeed it seems QPA may offers a command BlocksOfAlgebra which sounds as if it can do what you want.
UPDATE: I completely misread the problem, and as such linked to the wrong decomposition function (now fixed). But I am also now not sure anymore if this method actually works in characteristic 0, and in fact am starting to doubt it. I can't verify this right now, though -- my apologies if I mislead you here :-/.

Your link treats decomposition of modules. Are you suggesting applying it to the algebra $A$ as an $A \otimes A^{op}$-module?

No, I had a slip of mind and referenced the wrong function. Now correct. Thank you for pointing out my mistake!
